# High Dimension Text Classification , Efficient Way

Tags: algorithm, apache-spark, svm, text-classification, perceptron

A sub sample of our problem is as below.

We have 1600 address locations to find with Machine Learning.
Our training data is in form of

```
City Subdivision District number1-number2-number3
```

We have official data which show partitions of city

```
London Chelsea Kensington 2-3-15
London Chelsea Kensington 4-3-15
London Chelsea Battersea  3-4-2
London Greenwich Charlton 4-3-15
London Greenwich Coldharbour 1-2-1
```

We have 10K of these samples.

So our training data is 10K.

```
Training Data

----------


Label      | Features

Kensington | London Chelsea Kensington 5-1-1

Kensington | London Chelsea Kensington 4-3-15

Battersea  | London Chelsea Battersea  5-1-1

Battersea  | London Chelsea Battersea  4-2-1

Charlton   | London Greenwich Charlton 5-1-1

Coldharbour| London Greenwich Coldharbour 5-1-1


----------
```

Think numbers as address numbering. So not unique, not a distinctive feature.

What we need to guess is

```
----------


Chelsea Kensington 5ｰ1ｰ1 sea harbor = Kensington ( sea harbor some additional items which can exist in other addresses 
and can mislead our algorithms)

Kensington 5ｰ1ｰ1  =  Kensington ( Think 5-1-1 exists for lots of addresses and some algorithms (Bayes or Decision Trees)guess this as another address with 5-1-1 Charlton)

Kensington 5      =  Kensington ( One might think since it has only Kensington it will gues Kensington but if there is an address
as  xxx 5 5 5 Bayes thinks it is xxx )


----------
```

One would immediately say this needs ngram. But ngrams matches
very unrelated entries with high probability. Bayes with Ngram2 or Ngram3 finds lots of correct matches but they also claim for 99 probability  for wrong result.

I have tried Bayes,Decision Trees,Random Forests...
OnevsRest never finished on this high dimension.

Multi Layer Perceptron did not finish with 12K feature space.
Got out of memory errors.

I reduced dimension to 3000 but even with that did not see the  results.

SVM is not applicable since it is multi class.

**To sum up:**

My training data is so simple and do not contain so much information. (List of all addresses in a place)
Problem is high dimensional.(1600 districts)

My probable data will be unseen and unpredictable maybe.With some
typing errors.

I am thinking of doing some PCA(SVD) and then Multi Layer perceptron
or CNN.

But think I have 12000 vocabulary for 1600 classes.
I am not sure if there is a meaning for dimension reduction
for this problem.

So is anyone ever worked on a problem like this?

Comment: It seems that the label always equal to one of the features. Why would you use machine learning and not simple search?

Comment: Dear Lior ,Test data does not come as exactly. Maybe it is not readable. I am making it more readable. Think I do not always get label or there are multiple Battersea in different places.

Comment: Nonetheless, I don't think machine learning would prove to be the best way. I would break the input into names and numbers, and define some distance score between those and real addresses.

Comment: I think as you. Problem suffer from error function(distance score means same I think). I do not know if I am getting better.So functional loss style algorithms are useless.

Comment: Probabilistic ones are unreliable. Bayes gives %99 for some wrong results. If you use the input for decision tree, it can do with only one level of tree ,district itself. geometric ones like SVM are not for high dimension. Maybe I need to prove this is not a machine learning with this input. I am thinking of parameter generation of MultiLayer Perceptron and see if there is a magical relation with letters and output.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply ***remove all  non-letters*** (including digits) and possibly stopwords?   At that point the problem as shown above simply becomes : when you see some subset of `Set A` then return `B`.      { `A` -> `B' }

Example (after removal of non-letters):

```
{ London Chelsea Kensington } -> { Kensington}
```

So i presume also:

```
{ Chelsea Kensington } ->  { Kensington}

 { Kensington } ->  { Kensington}
```

Without any further requirements provided this is solved by a `Set of Sets`. A simple solution is to compare the intersection of a new Set To Be Predicted against all Labeled Sets and find the "winner". If you have many many Sets then you will want to have a forest of `Trie`'s of Terms - that represent the members of the Sets - to help make the search tractable

Comment: Dear javadba, Training data is clear but test data(or real) will not come as Kensington. probably without chelsea it will come as Knsigton or Kenston.  At that time problem falls into ngram style logics. Ngrams are so good with Countvector and TF-IDF ,in low space.(20 class). But when it is 1600 class they got so bad they claim wrong results with %99 probability.(because it is a character sequence and a wrong version of something resembles another thing so much)

Comment: Well that is a fundamentally different problem: and you should ensure your training data reflects the anticipated test data.  My answer is directed to the question you posed above.

Comment: I agree. I am given a well defined training set and need to guess bad input. At least ,I need bad input to merge this set. Problem definition is not good. Best I can do could be generating some columns and let the Perceptron do the magic.